# Can't get javascript to assign id to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script file on called scripts.js, which contains only the following code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".btnDelete", function() {
var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
$("#hdBookId").val(trid);
});
```

Nothing else.  Literally nothing else at all in that file.  I've checked and when I load the page the script file is being loaded.  I set a breakpoint at the 'var trid' bit, and when I click on the button with the btnDelete class name, the breakpoint never gets hit, the script doesn't fire.  Anyone any idea why?

Comment: Replace `"body"` with `document` *(without quotes)*

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome, `body` is just an element, and when you add scripts to the head section, you either need to delegate to `document` or use a DOM ready handler.

Comment: It should be noted that using the `document` element for event delegation is extremely inefficient. It forces the event to bubble up through every layer of the DOM. Try delegating the event to the closest element that wraps all the `.btnDelete` buttons such as maybe the `<table>` element which contains all of these buttons.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that, good advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `$(document).on("click"...` instead of `$("body").on("click"...`?